# Jackson not recognizing fields that exist

Tags: java, json, jackson

So here's my JSON

```
{"totalSize":46,"done":true,"records":[{"Name":"Wamu I","Start_Date__c":"2016-09-26T16:56:10.000+0000","Status__c":"Completed","Type__c":"Your were expecting success, but In reality it was I, Dio!!!"}]}
```

And here are my two entity classes:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EsidesiJobEntity {

    @JsonProperty("totalSize")
    private @Getter @Setter Integer totalSize;

    @JsonProperty("done")
    private @Getter @Setter Boolean isDone;

    @JsonProperty("records")
    private @Getter @Setter List<KarsEntity> records;

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public String toString(){

        List<String> recordsObjectString = new ArrayList<String>();

        this.records.forEach((record) -> 
        {
            recordsObjectString.add(record.toString());
        });
        return "{ totalSize:"+this.totalSize+", isDone:"+this.isDone+", records:["+recordsObjectString.toString()+"]";
    }

}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class KarsEntity {

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private @Getter @Setter String name;

    @JsonProperty("Start_Date__c")
    private @Getter @Setter String startDate;

    @JsonProperty("Status__c")
    private @Getter @Setter String status;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "{ name:"+this.name+", startDate:"+this.startDate+", status:"+this.status+"}";
    }
}
```

for some reason, when I map that json string to the EsidesiJobEntity, I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized field "totalSize"
```

BUT IT DEFINITELY EXISTS IN BOTH IN BOTH THE JSON AND THE ENTITY!

Here's the code I wrote to map the string to the entity for reference:

```
EsidesiEntity apexJobResponseEntity;

ObjectMapper apexMapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    apexJobResponseEntity = apexMapper.readValue(apexResponseString, EsidesiEntity.class);
} ...
```

Am I missing something really basic?

(BTW, If there's some inconsistency in the Class/Entity names, its because I renamed them before posting them online. Let me know and I'll fix them as I see them. )

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you should do like below 
apexJobResponse = apexMapper.readValue("your json string", EsidesiEntity.class);

Comment: what is apexResponse ? is this your json string ?

Comment: actually, apexResponse is a string and apexJobResponse is the object. Let me make this a little clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html). Jackson can't see your getter and setter methods.

So you have two options:

1. Do not use Lombok and implement the getter and setter methods
2. Use Lombok with this additional library: [jackson-lombok](https://github.com/xebia/jackson-lombok)

If you are using maven, so add *jackson-lombok* to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xebia</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Configure then your `ObjectMapper` in this way:

```
ObjectMapper apexMapper = new ObjectMapper();
apexMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonLombokAnnotationIntrospector());
[...]
```

Comment: So I decided to take the non-lombok route (at least to get it working), yet get the same error. I tried with and without "@JsonProperty(...)" annotations on the getters and setters as well.

Comment: Hm. Ok, I'm sure there is no need to annotate the methods. Are you sure you are using the newest jackson version?

Comment: I was assuming since the method names resemble the java variables, rather than the JSON properties, that I may as well annotate those as well. It didn't work however.

Comment: Can you prepare a little example on github or update your question with more code?

Comment: Okay I figured out what I did wrong. You fixed one of the problems (The bigger one). The other problem occurred after I made the getters and setters. For some reason, Eclipse auto generated private getters and setters. I fixed those and it started working. Thanks!

Comment: Do you still want a github model? I can still prepare that If you think it would help others out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(youJson);
MyPojo pojo = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, MyPojo.class);
```